# Form elements and associated labels

Tags: javascript, html, labeling

How to make associated labels for form elements in below code?

```
render() {
return (
  <section className="col">
    <div className="input-group">
      <input type="text" 
      id="search-input" 
      ref="searchInput" 
      className="form-control" 
      placeholder="Filter location..." 
      onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <span className="input-group-addon">Filter</span>
    </div>
  </section>
)
}
```

Comment: Use `label` tag and set `for` attribute to be equal to the`id` of your input. Alternatively, wrap the label tag around your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below.

```
<section className="col">
    <div className="input-group">
      <label for="search-input">Filter</label>
      <input type="text" 
      id="search-input" 
      ref="searchInput" 
      className="form-control" 
      placeholder="Filter location..." 
      onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </div>
  </section>
```

Create label and give input elements id to label's for attribute